# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException with org.w3c.dom.Element field

Tags: json, spring, apache-kafka, jackson, marshalling

I try send message to kafka and get this message in another service. I add

```
org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer //consumer side
org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer //produser side
```

And I try send object with field:

```
org.w3c.dom.Element;

@XmlAnyElement
protected Element any;
```

Message send sucessfuly but on consumer side I get error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[123, 34, 114, 101...

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem deserializing property 'any' (expected type: [simple type, class org.w3c.dom.Element]; actual type: `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl`), problem: java.lang.ClassCastException@4db05b26
```

I show this mesage in topik by this command:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic  --from-beginning
```

And this message look right:

```
"to": "eyJzaWQi...",
 "messagePrimaryContent": {
    "any": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<ImportCh...(another xml text)"
 },
 "personalSignature": null,
```

**How do I deserialize this message?**

If I send this object without `org.w3c.dom.Element` all work correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in deserialize records in  123, 34, 114, 101.., due to the wrong scheme. On the consumer side, you have a different format to deserialize.
You can avoid those data by doing some try-catch and avoiding such kind of record or else change to correct scheme at consumer side.

Code to avoid wrong scheme records.

```
try {
                    records = consumer.poll(10000);
                } catch (SerializationException e) {
                    String s = e.getMessage().split("Error deserializing key/value for partition ")[1].split(". If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.")[0];
                    String topics = s.split("-")[0];
                    int offset = Integer.valueOf(s.split("offset ")[1]);
                    int partition = Integer.valueOf(s.split("-")[1].split(" at")[0]);

                    TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topics, partition);
                    //log.info("Skipping " + topic + "-" + partition + " offset " + offset);
                    consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset + 1);
                }
```